# cast error :cast ArrayType(DoubleType,true) to DoubleType

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have parquet file which contain id,features  .when I use cast error 
[image]

> cast ArrayType(DoubleType,true) to DoubleType

```
val training = spark.read.parquet("/usr/local/spark/dataset/data/user")
 val df = training.selectExpr("cast(id as int) id","cast(features as double) features")
 val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("features" )).setOutputCol("feature")
 val data = assembler.transform(df)
```

this error appear

```
cannot resolve 'CAST(`features` AS DOUBLE)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast ArrayType(DoubleType,true) to DoubleType; line 1 pos 0;
```

how to solve it?

**After edit error appear**

> java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [D

Comment: "features" column contains array of DoubleType so it can't be casted to a DoubleType.

Answer (score 0):

"features" column contains array of DoubleType so it can't be casted to a DoubleType. You convert this column to a Vector using `Vectors.dense`. Then use `VectorAssembler` on columns containing double and vector.

Something like,

```
val training = spark.read.parquet("/usr/local/spark/dataset/data/user")
 val df = training.map{ r =>
   (Vectors.dense(r.getAs[Array[Double]]("features")),r.getAs[Double]("id"))
  }.toDF("features","id")
 val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("features" )).setOutputCol("feature")
 val data = assembler.transform(df)
```

Comment: yes,but error  appear scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [Double]

Comment: can you please update the question with data that can be used to reproduce the error. Show the schema. Essentially you just need to match the data types to extract doubles, convert double to vector and then feed that to VectorAssembler.